# Can I have times greater than 24 hours in postrgres

Tags: postgresql

I am doing timetabling stuff. In railway timetables, if the service starts one day and ends the next, then the convention is to use a +24 hour clock. So if it gets in at 6 in the morning, it's given as thirty-o'clock from the previous start date. This date can be, and in this case is, in a separate table so can't be combined.

Am I going to have to store it in seconds and convert it back on output to the native export format, which expects a +24 hour clock format, and also on the UI. If it means storing stuff as TimeDate from Thursday 1st jan then I'd rather just use an integer and create a virtual type within my application.

Or is there an easy way to relax this 24:00 max on a time field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [`interval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) type.

When speaking of time there are three types of time (all of which have surprising complexity):

- A specific time. A Timestamp.
- A Duration of time
- An Interval of time (the time between two specific times.. similar to above but different).

Postgres in this case uses `interval` to mean duration (but there is a difference in many time libraries such as Joda... ie a year is not always a year precisely).

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to store such information as an [`interval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT). You could use `interval minute` as well if you are going to record arrival times by the minute. Interval can take on any (reasonable) value, so `30:00` is completely valid to indicate that the arrival is 30 hours after some starting point (either departure or midnight of scheduled departure date, depending on your logic). Since an `interval` is a built-in data type, you can simply add it to other `date`s or `timestamp`s and get sensible results at database and UI level.

Answer (score -1):

Mark -

That sounds like it could be a challenge to get used to - I've never heard of that sort of time keeping before! With that said, I would not try and force a square peg in a round hole with the database field. Instead, I would use your application to keep track of how you want to display the time and allow the database to do what does best with timestamps. Timestamps are typically stored in epoch form (number of seconds), so store your times as normal and create a wrapper/helper function to display your +24 hour clock format to your users.